# "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080" even though i checked the port by using netstat -ano

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

"java.net.bindexception address already in use null 8080" even though i checked the port by using netstat -ano to check and found out that no such port was open before running my project on tomcat 7 server.

Can anyone provide me with some pointer.

Thanks,
pkalyan

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on windows machine check your host file is correct or not.
You can set it to default for your OS(Xp/Windows 7) by following the instructions here.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/972034

In my case it was causing the issue, and after making it to default it was working fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the advise i removed the tomcat and installed new copy and now it works like a charm.